# How to get an item from the String[] attribute in JSTL/JSP tag

Tags: java, jsp, el, jsp-tags

In plain JSP I can get first item by EL `${form.items[0]}`, but in a JSP tag the same expression throws the following exception:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find property 0 in class
>    java.lang.String

The value of `${form.items}` is `[Ljava.lang.String;@315e5b60`.

JSP tag code is:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="items" required="true" %>
${items[0]}
```

JSP code is:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<t:input items="${form.items}"></t:input>
```

Maybe I forgot type of the attribute or something else? Why is the way to access values different in JSP and JSP tag?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to specify the expeded type of the custom tag attribute. By default, it's `java.lang.String`, and the JSP container coerces the attribute to a string before passing it to your tag. It thus calls toString on your String array.

```
<%@ attribute name="items" required="true" type="java.lang.String[]" %>
```

or

```
<%@ attribute name="items" required="true" type="[Ljava.lang.String" %>
```

should do the trick. If neither does, using

```
<%@ attribute name="items" required="true" type="java.lang.Object" %>
```

should, but it's less clear.

Comment: Thanks, first solution works (type="java.lang.String[]"). Second - doesn't work, I tried it before.

Comment: Using java.lang.Object allows the tag to get both arrays and java.util.List. That may be useful in some cases too.